# Does $X_n \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} X$ imply $X_n^2 \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow} X^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose $X_n,X$ are random variables with $X_n \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} X$. Does this imply $X_n^2 \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow} X^2$?

$X_n \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} X$ means $E(|X_n-X|^2) \rightarrow 0$ and what we have to show is that $E(|X_n^2 - X^2|) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Convergence in $L^2$ is often meant as assuming that $X$ and every $X_n$ are all in $L^2$. Then indeed the implication holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Did and saz mentioned, the standard definition of convergence in $L^2$ stipulates that all the random variables involved be twice integrable. However, OP took the trouble of defining in their question what $L^2$ convergence meant for them, and this definition does not involve the above-mentioned stipulation. Moreover, after I posted my original answer 15 hours ago, which covered only the case that $X$ was twice integrable, OP commented on my answer and told me in no uncertain terms that they were interested in the case where there were no restrictions on any of the random variables involved. The fact that OP did not accept my answer then, which was the only game in town at that point, further drove the point home. Therefore, in what follows I do not presuppose this condition. In fact, I don't even presuppose that any of the random variables are integrable.

***Case 1: $\mathbf{E(X^2) < \infty}$***

If $E(X^2)<\infty$, the implication holds.

Firstly note that, given a sequence $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$ of real numbers,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = 0 \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n^2=0.
$$

Secondly note that, since $E(|X_n-X|^2)\rightarrow 0$, we may assume, w.l.g., that the sequence $(E(|X_1-X|^2), E(|X_2-X|^2),\dots)$ is bounded, say by $L \in [0,\infty)$.

Thirdly note that we may assume, w.l.g., that the sequence $(E(X_1^2), E(X_2^2), \dots)$ is bounded by $M:=L + 2\sqrt{LE(X^2)}+E(X^2)$. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
E(X_n^2) &= E\Big(\big((X_n-X)+X\big)^2\Big) \\
&\leq E(|X_n-X|^2)+2E(|X_n-X||X|) + E(X^2) \\
&\overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq} E(|X_n-X|^2)+2\sqrt{E(|X_n-X|^2)E(X^2)} + E(X^2) \\
&\leq L + 2\sqrt{LE(X^2)} + E(X^2).
\end{align}
$$

Now write
$$
\begin{align}
E(|X_n^2-X^2|) &= E(|X_n^2-X_nX+X_nX-X^2|) \\
&= E(|X_n(X_n-X)+X(X_n-X)|) \\
&\leq E(|X_n||X_n-X|)+E(|X||X_n-X|).
\end{align}
$$

To see that the left-hand summand of the last expression converges to zero, note that
$$
E^2(|X_n||X_n-X|) \overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq} \underset{\leq M}{E(X_n^2)}\ \cdot\ \underset{\rightarrow 0\text{ by assump.}}{E(|X_n-X|^2)}\rightarrow 0.
$$

A similar argument shows that the other summand converges to zero too.

***Case 2: $\mathbf{E(X^2) = \infty}$***

If $E(X^2) = \infty$, the implication does not hold. Here's a counter-example.

For every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ define
$$
\begin{align}
a_n &:= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}(n+1), \\
b_n &:= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n}(n-1) = a_n\frac{n-1}{n+1}.
\end{align}
$$

Verify that every pair $(a_n, b_n)$, $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, satisfies $a_n > b_n > 0$, and solves the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{align}
(a - b)^2 &= n, \\
a^2 - b^2 &= n^2.
\end{align}
$$

We will later use the following estimate:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n-1}{n}a_n - b_n &= \frac{n-1}{n}a_n - \frac{n-1}{n+1}a_n \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)(n-1)a_n \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Set
$$
\begin{align}
C_2 &:= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2}, \\
C_3 &:= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3},
\end{align}
$$
and define, for every $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$,
$$
S_n := \begin{cases}
0 &, n = 0, \\
\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1/C_3}{i^3} &, n \geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Consider the standard probability space $([0,1),\mathcal{B},\lambda)$. We now define two random variables, $X_0, X$ on this probability space as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
X_0 &:= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n\mathbb{1}_{[S_{n-1},S_n)}, \\
X &:= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n\mathbb{1}_{[S_{n-1},S_n)}.
\end{align}
$$

Furthermore, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ we define
$$
X_n := \frac{1}{n} X_0 + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)X.
$$
Observe that $X_0 > X \geq 0$, and therefore, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $X_n > X \geq 0$. Also note that, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$,
$$
\frac{n-1}{n} X_0 - X \geq 0.
$$

Then, for every $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$,
$$
\begin{align}
E(|X_n-X|^2) &= \frac{1}{n^2} E\big((X_0 - X)^2\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_i - b_i)^2 \frac{1/C_3}{i^3} \\
&= \frac{1/C_3}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{i^3} \\
&= \frac{C_2/C_3}{n^2}, \\
E\big(|X_n^2-X^2|\big) &= E\big(X_n^2-X^2\big) \\
&= E\Big(\big(\frac{1}{n}X_0 + (1-\frac{1}{n})X\big)^2 - X^2\Big) \\
&= E\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}X_0^2 + 2\frac{n-1}{n^2}X_0X + \big(1-\frac{1}{n}\big)^2X^2 - X^2\Big) \\
&= E\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}X_0^2 + 2\frac{n-1}{n^2}X_0X - \big(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\big)X^2\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}E\Big(X_0^2 + X^2\Big) + \frac{2}{n}E\Big(\big(\frac{n-1}{n}X_0-X\big)X\Big) \\
&\geq \frac{1}{n^2}E\Big(X_0^2 + X^2\Big) \\
&\geq \frac{1}{n^2}E\Big(X_0^2 - X^2\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_i^2-b_i^2)\frac{1/C_3}{i^3} \\
&= \frac{1/C_3}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i^2}{i^3} \\
&= \infty.
\end{align}
$$

***Case 3: $\mathbf{E(X^2) = \infty}$ revisited***

In this section I will show that it is possible to salvage some of the flavor of Case 1 even if $E(X^2) = \infty$, namely I will show that if $E(X^2) = \infty$, then $E(X_n^2) \rightarrow \infty$.

Suppose to the contrary. Then there is some $T \in [0,\infty)$, such that, for all $i$ in some infinite subset $I \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots\}$, $E(X_i^2) \leq T$. Then, for every $i \in I$,
$$
\begin{align}
E(X^2) &= E\Big(\big((X-X_i)+X_i\big)^2\Big) \\
&\leq E(|X_i-X|^2)+2E(|X_i-X||X_i|) + E(X_i^2) \\
&\overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq} E(|X_i-X|^2)+2\sqrt{E(|X_i-X|^2)E(X_i^2)} + E(X_i^2) \\
&\leq L + 2\sqrt{LT} + T,
\end{align}
$$
a contradiction. ($L$ is the same bound introduced in Case 1.)

This, coupled with Case 1, shows that, if $X, X_1, X_2, \dots$ are integrable random variables defined over the same probability space, then $E\big(|X_n-X|^2\big) \rightarrow 0$ implies $V(X_n) \rightarrow V(X)$, and this holds regardless of whether $E(X^2)$ is finite.

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question is that I read that $X_n \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} X$ implies $var(X_n) \to var(X)$ (without any assuptions on $X_n^2,X^2$). I tried to prove this but failed as I think we need $X_n^2 \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow} X^2$ to show that $var(X_n) \to var(X)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mahu_83: I have added an addendum, which together with the first part of the proof, implies that, if $X_n\overset{L^2}{\rightarrow}X$ (in the sense you defined in your question), then $\mathrm{var}(X_n)\rightarrow\mathrm{var}(X)$, without any assumptions on $X_n^2$ and $X^2$. Please consider accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @mahu_83: I have now answered your question completely, in all the generality that you required. Additionally, I answered the question that you posed in your comment above (see Case 3). Please consider accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: "Please consider accepting my answer." I wish people would stop posting these requests. Common decency and all that...

Comment: Following the logic of this answer (which, IMHO, is irrelevant to the question but...), one should also decide what happens when the random variables are not in $L^1$ since then the variances do not exist. Note that "not in $L^2$" in this post seems to mean "in $L^1$ but not in $L^2$".

Comment: @Did: If you can please point out the place where I made the assumption that any of the random variables were in $L^1$, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is V(X) in the last sentence of your post if X is not integrable? (Note that my previous comment already points to this exact fact, hence you are making me parrot.)

Comment: @Did: This is the only place. It is an after thought, and I explicitly make the assumption of integrability there. This in no way affects any of the proceedings until then.

Comment: @EvanAad Thank you for the answer, I accepted it, but before I had to read it carefully.

Comment: @mahu_83: Thanks for taking the time to read it, and thanks for accepting it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

Since

$$X_n^2 - X^2 = (X_n-X) (X_n+X)$$

we have by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n^2-X^2|) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(|X_n+X|^2)}. \tag{1}$$

The first term on the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. For the second one, note that

$$\mathbb{E}(|X_n+X|^2) \leq 2 \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) + 2 \mathbb{E}(X^2) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 4 \mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty.$$

(Here, we used the elementary inequality $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2+2b^2$.) Consequently, the claim follows by letting $n \to \infty$ in $(1)$.

**Remark:** The standard definition of $L^2$-convergence $X_n \to X$ requires that $X \in L^2$; note that this is, in particular, satisfied if $\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|^2) \to 0$ and $X_k \in L^2$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why do we have $2 \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) + 2 \mathbb{E}(X^2) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 4 \mathbb{E}(X^2)$? I think $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2) \to \mathbb{E}(X^2)$ is the statement we have to prove.

Comment: @mahu_83 No, we have to prove that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|^2) \to 0$; this is stronger than $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2) \to \mathbb{E}(X^2)$. The convergence $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2) \to \mathbb{E}(X^2)$ is a direct consequence of the reverse triangle inequality (for the $L^2$ norm), i.e. $$|\|X_n\|_{L^2}-\|X\|_{L^2}| \leq \|X_n-X\|_{L^2} \to 0.$$ Alternatively, note that $$\mathbb{E}(X_n^2) = \mathbb{E}((X_n-X+X)^2) \leq 2 \mathbb{E}((X_n-X)^2) + 2 \mathbb{E}(X^2) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 2 \mathbb{E}(X^2).$$

Comment: Nice, but I think you wanted to write "have to prove that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n^2-X^2|) \to 0$" in the first line. 

Your "alternatively" part shows that the limit is bounded and finite but does not tell you what the limit is, am I correct?

Comment: @mahu_83 Proving the $L^2$-convergence is exactly what my answer is about.... please reread my answer carefully....

Comment: My comment refered to your comment, not to your answer.

Comment: @mahu_83 Ah, sorry. So, yes, the "alternatively" part shows the boundedness, but this is enough ... note that if $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence and $a_n$ converges to $0$, then $a_n \cdot b_n  \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, then all is clear. Thank you.